# Flatten List with fold

Tags: dart

I was able to flatten a list using fold

```
flattenWithFold(Iterable list) => list.fold([], (List xs, s) {
s is Iterable ? xs.addAll(flattenWithFold(s)) : xs.add(s);
   return xs;
});
```

When executing

```
print(flattenWithFold([1,[3,5,[1,2]],[2,1],6]));
```

It produces correct result [1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6]

But when I try to refactor to use ..add, It produces incorrect result

```
flattenWithFold1(Iterable list) => list.fold([], (List xs, s) => xs..add(
              s is Iterable ? xs.addAll(flattenWithFold1(s)) : s));
```

Can someone please explain why there are null [1, 3, 5, 1, 2, null, null, 2, 1, null, 6] when executing ?

```
print(flattenWithFold1([1,[3,5,[1,2]],[2,1],6]));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting `null` in your result because if `s` is an `Iterable` you are doing `xs..add(xs.addAll(flattenWithFold1(s))`. `addAll` is a `void` method, but since you're using it as an expression, it returns `null`. So you are adding the flattened elements to `xs`, but then you're adding `null`, which is the return value of `void` methods.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @Harry. Is there an effective way to flatten using fold without using return? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to cascade the addAll as well. I'm not sure why fold is a requirement, because you could also do flatten(Iterable list) => list.expand((item) => item is Iterable ? flatten(item) : [item]);

Comment: Using expand is a efficient way. I just was trying to see if there is another efficient way with fold. Thanks @Alan

Comment: I found a way to do it  `flattenWithFold(Iterable list) => list.fold([], (List xs, s) =>
   s is Iterable ? (xs..addAll(flattenWithFold(s))) : (xs..add(s)));`

Comment: It's not particularly effective to build the intermediate lists and do`addAll` with them afterwards. Alternative: `_rec(accumulator, element) => element is Iterable ? element.fold(accumulator, _rec) : (accumulator..add(element)); flat(Iterable elements) => _rec([], elements);`